# C++ lotto number generator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm working on a program that must make an array of 5 random numbers between 0-9, I must then ask the user to enter 5 numbers between 0-9 and store that in and array, then compare them and show if they have gotten all them right. I wrote it all out but it keeps giving me this error

```
Error   1   error C1075: end of file found before the left brace '{' at 
'c:\users\bigt\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication2\
consoleapplication2\source.cpp(9)' 
was matched c:\users\bigt\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\
consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\source.cpp  65  1   
ConsoleApplication2
```

which makes me think I have a logical error, can anyone help me find where I'm doing wrong here?

```
//#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib> 
using namespace std;

//void showValues(int[], int);

int main()
{
    const int array_size = 5;
    int numbers[array_size];
    int win_num[array_size];
    int count = 0;

    cout << "enter your altto drawing" <<endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        cin >> numbers[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0 ; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        win_num[i] = rand()%10;
    }

    for (int i =0; i < array_size; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] != win_num[i])
        {
            cout << "sorry try again" << endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            count++;
        }
    if (count == 5)
    {
        cout << " you win" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " you did not win, you had" << count << "right numbers" << endl;
    }
    cout << "the winning numbers are" << endl;

    for( int i = 0; i < array_size ; i ++)
    {
        cout << win_num[i] << " ";
    }

    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should use the `<random>` header for pseudorandom number generation.

Comment: thats very strange is i was missing my } in the for statment why didnt my IDE show that i had a syntax error?

Answer (score 4):

You missed one closing `}` here:

```
for (int i =0; i < array_size; i++)
{
    if (numbers[i] != win_num[i])
    {
        cout << "sorry try again" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        count++;
    }
}//^^this one is missing
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not closed the block of the third `for`-loop.